# PHP str_ireplace for array

Tags: php

I am trying to remove certain strings from an array of strings

```
$replace = array(
    're: ', 're:', 're',
    'fw: ', 'fw:', 'fw',
    '[Ticket ID: #'.$ticket["ticketnumber"].'] ',
);

$available_subjects = array($ticket["subject"], $update["subject"]);
```

I tried using these loops

This replaced words like "You're" because of the "re"

```
foreach($replace as $r) {
    $available_subjects = str_ireplace($r, '', $available_subjects);
}
```

And the same with this one

```
foreach($replace as $r) {
    $available_subjects = preg_replace('/\b'.$r.'\b/i', '', $available_subjects);
}
```

So I want to match the whole word, and not part of words

Comment: Hello Charlie! Could you add some input string, and what you expect at the end so we can help with your regex rule? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would replace Ticket IDs statically like you did:

```php
$ticket_prefix = '[Ticket ID: #' . $ticket["ticketnumber"] . '] ';
$available_subjects = str_ireplace($ticket_prefix, '', $available_subjects);
```

Then, I would use a regular expression to replace `re` and `fw`:

```php
$available_subjects = preg_replace('#\b(fw|re):?\s*\b#i', '', $available_subjects);
```